# IntelliJ Idea unable to execute java Program

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to learn Java from an online class, however I am having problems following the instructor's video.
[image: This]
 is his screen, where he is trying to print a line.
My screen looks like
[image: this.]
As you can see, the "out" part of System.out is not the same on our screens, and the icon for class is different on both our screens as well. The main problem I am having is I'm not able to run the line of code that I wrote. I apologize if this question has been asked already, I was not sure what keywords I would use to search this problem.

Comment: The only difference I see is the syntax highlighting, which could be due to a number of reasons.  Does your code run properly?  This is the bigger question.

Comment: Possible reasons: not set jdk; not set src directory.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I try to run the code in the IDE but there is no option to run the application. All it does is give me the option to "edit configurations"

Comment: @Tony I am seeing a bar above the code window which says "Project SDK is not defined" is this what you mean by unset jdk?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`As you can see, the "out" part of System.out is not the same on our screens`

This probably is due to the fact that you haven't opened up a Java Project. As you can probably see in the Two Images, the instructor's image, has A Project hierarchy on the left, while yours is empty. Therefore, To correct this Try The Following Steps:

```
File->New Project->Java Project
```

Now follow the onscreen instructions to create the Java Project. Then the project would be created.  Now expand the project on the left pane, and do it until you find a folder named `src` . Select the folder, and choose new Class, and then You can create your new Classes

`The main problem I am having is I'm not able to run the line of code that I wrote.`

This is probably due to the fact that you Have not set up your JDK path in IntellIJ. This is backed up by the fact, that your run button (The Green Arrow on the Instructor's), is grayed. To fix this, click On the small Button beside the `arrow`. There, Click On `edit Configurations`. The following Window should pop up

[image]

If Default is not expanded, then expand it and Choose Application. The Window Should probably be like this :-

Then Click On the `plus` icon on the top

There, Enter You Main Class(The Class Which has `public static main void(String args[])`)

If you can't, choose the `...` option, and choose
[image]

Finally, select the JRE path, that is, the location where you installed The JRE.

Also, make sure that You have the 'path' environment variable set to the `bin` of your jdk Installation Folder.

Ask if you have any problems doing this.

Answer (score 0):

First you shoud do this: File- New-  Project... Then create new project. And then you click right mouse button on src folder(in your new project), choose new "Java class" and copy code to that new class. And then you'll be able to run your main method.

Problem is that you just use java-file from somewhere (desktop, probably), but you should have it inside your project.